# Exceldna / WPF Window keyboard input is redirected to Excel

Tags: wpf, window, typing, excel-dna

I have an Excel-dna addin which creates a WPF window with a Textbox in it and show it.
When i call Window.Show() and type something into the Textbox, the keyboard input is redirected to the selected Excel-Cell instead of into the Textbox.
When i call Window.ShowDialog() it works as expected.

My goal is to have something like a tool window being able to react on changing cell selection in Excel (but also being able to type into Textboxes in that tool window).

Comment: You probably need a custom pane.